# NumPy template matching SQDIFF with `sliding window_view`

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, stride

The SQDIFF is defined as [openCV definition](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#gga3a7850640f1fe1f58fe91a2d7583695dab65c042ed62c9e9e095a1e7e41fe2773). (I believe they omit channels)

[image: SQDIFF]

Which in junior numpy Python should be

```py
A = np.arange(27, dtype=np.float32)
A = A.reshape(3,3,3) # The "image"
B = np.ones([2, 2, 3], dtype=np.float32) # window
rw, rh = A.shape[0] - B.shape[0] + 1, A.shape[1] - B.shape[1] + 1 # End result size
result = np.zeros([rw, rh])
for i in range(rw):
    for j in range(rh):
        w = A[i:i + B.shape[0], j:j + B.shape[1]]
        res =  B - w
        result[i, j] = np.sum(
            res ** 2
        )
cv_result = cv.matchTemplate(A, B, cv.TM_SQDIFF) # this result is the same as the simple for loops
assert np.allclose(cv_result, result)
```

This is comparatively slow solution. I have read about `sliding_window_view` but cannot get it correct.

```py
# This will fail with these large arrays but is ok for smaller ones
A = np.random.rand(1028, 1232, 3).astype(np.float32)
B = np.random.rand(248, 249, 3).astype(np.float32)
locations = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(A, B.shape)
sqdiff = np.sum((B - locations) ** 2, axis=(-1,-2, -3, -4)) # This will fail with normal sized images
```

will fail with `MemoryError` even if the result easily fits to memory. How can I produce similar results to the `cv2.matchTemplate` function with this faster way?

Comment: Can you please post your "normal sized image" and normal size window? The sample you have posted does not reproduce the `MemoryError`...

Comment: I have generated a source and a template with `np.random.rand`.

Comment: Now it's reproducible. I am getting an error: `numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 530. GiB for an array with shape (781, 984, 1, 248, 249, 3) and data type float32`. NumPy tries to allocate memory for storing all the results of `(B - locations)` at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a last resort, you may perform the computation in tiles, instead of computing "all at once".

`np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view` returns a **view** of the data, so it doesn't consume a lot of RAM.

The expression `B - locations` can't use a view, and requires the RAM for storing an array with shape (781, 984, 1, 248, 249, 3) of float elements.

The total RAM for storing `B - locations` is `781*984*1*248*249*3*4` = 569,479,908,096 bytes.

---

For avoiding the need for storing `B - locations` at the RAM at once, we may compute `sqdiff` in tiles, when "tile" computation requires less RAM.

A simple tiles division is using every row as a tile - loop over the rows of `sqdiff`, and compute the output row by row.

Example:

```
sqdiff = np.zeros((locations.shape[0], locations.shape[1]), np.float32)  # Allocate an array for storing the result.

# Compute sqdiff row by row instead of computing all at once.
for i in range(sqdiff.shape[0]):
    sqdiff[i, :] = np.sum((B - locations[i, :, :, :, :, :]) ** 2, axis=(-1, -2, -3, -4))
```

---

Executable code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

A = np.random.rand(1028, 1232, 3).astype(np.float32)
B = np.random.rand(248, 249, 3).astype(np.float32)
locations = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(A, B.shape)

cv_result = cv2.matchTemplate(A, B, cv2.TM_SQDIFF)  # this result is the same as the simple for loops

#sqdiff = np.sum((B - locations) ** 2, axis=(-1, -2, -3, -4))  # This will fail with normal sized images

sqdiff = np.zeros((locations.shape[0], locations.shape[1]), np.float32)  # Allocate an array for storing the result.

# Compute sqdiff row by row instead of computing all at once.
for i in range(sqdiff.shape[0]):
    sqdiff[i, :] = np.sum((B - locations[i, :, :, :, :, :]) ** 2, axis=(-1, -2, -3, -4))

assert np.allclose(cv_result, sqdiff)
```

---

I know the solution is a bit disappointing... But it is the only generic solution I could find.

Comment: I tried this approach and the performance is even poorer than double for loops. It is a shame, especially when `openCV` was 0.22s and these are ~200s.

Comment: Yes it's slow... I guess OpenCV uses a trick for reducing the number of computations.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

is equivalent to
[image]
where the 'star' operation is a cross-correlation, the 1_[m, n] is a window the size of the template, and 1_[k, l] is a window with the size of the image.

You can compute the cross-correlation terms using 'scipy.signal.correlate' and find the matches by looking for local minima in the square difference map.
You might want to do some non-minimum suppression too.
This solution will require orders of magnitude less memory to store.

For more help, please post a reproducible example with an image and template that are valid for the algorithm. Using noise will result in meaningless outputs.

Comment: Thank you for your interest! I am trying to find out how to implement this with `sliding_window_view` as I feel I am not the only one struggling to remove double for loops in `NumPy` for close to this type of computation. If this were to go to real application, I would just use `openCV` or construct a kernel myself. The inputs are just for demonstration's sake.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use 'sliding_window_view' for this problem because it creates every possible view in the image with the size of the template. This is the reason for the large memory requirement. In other words, this is impossible. But it's also unnecessary because you can do the same thing much more efficiently with the method I proposed, which includes no explicit loops.